# boost::asio: register fd for EPOLLIN / EPOLLOUT once and leave it registered

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a tcp client which is serviced by a `boost::asio::io_context` running on a single thread. It is configured `non-blocking`.

Reads/writes to this client are only ever done within the context of this thread.

I am using [`async_wait`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/async_wait.html) to await for the socket to become readable/writeable.

```
void Client::awaitReadable()
{
    _socket.async_wait(tcp::socket::wait_read, std::bind_front(&Client::onReadable, this));
}
```

Whenever the socket becomes readable, my `onReadable` callback is fired, and I read all available data until receive `asio::error::would_block`.

```
void Client::onReadable(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        while (1) // drain the socket
        {
            const std::size_t len = _socket.read_some(_read_buf.writeBuf(), ec);
            if (ec)
                break;
            else
                _read_buf.advance(len);
        }
    }
    if (ec == asio::error::would_block)
    {
        const std::size_t read = _read_cb(*this, _read_buf.readBuf();
        _read_buf.dataRead(read);

        awaitReadable(); // I have to await readable again
    }
    else
    {
        onDisconnected(ec);
    }
}
```

Once I've drained the socket I then need to call `awaitReadable` again to re-register my `onReadable` callback.

This necessarily involves a call to `epoll_ctl`, which effectively changes absolutely nothing.

When writing to the socket, the process if similar.

First, if the socket is currently writeable, I will attempt to send the data immediately. If, during the write, the I receive `asio::error::would_block`, I buffer the remaining unsent data and call my `awaitWriteable` function

```
void Client::write(Data buf)
{
    if (_writeable)
    {
        const auto [ sent, ec ] = doWrite(buf); // calls awaitWriteable if would_block
        if (ec == asio::error::would_block)
            _write_buf.add(buf.data() + sent, buf.size() - sent);
    }
    else
    {
        _write_buf.add(buf); // will be sent when socket becomes writeable
    }
}
```

The `awaitWriteable` function is very similar to the `awaitReadable` version

```
void Client::awaitWriteable()
{
    _socket.async_wait(tcp::socket::wait_write, std::bind_front(&Client::onWriteable, this));
}
```

When the socket becomes writeable again I will be notified, and I will write more data to the socket.

```
void Client::onWriteable(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        _writeable = true;
        if (!_write_buf.empty())
        {
            const auto [ sent, ec ] = doWrite(_write_buf.writeBuf());
            if (!ec)
                _write_buf.sent(sent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        onDisconnected(ec);
    }
}
```

The actual writing is factored out into a separate function as it is called both by the "synchronous write" function, and from the `OnWriteable` callback

```
std::pair<std::size_t, boost::system::error_code> Client::doWrite(Data buf)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    std::size_t sent = _socket.write_some(buf + sent, ec);

    if (ec)
    {
        if (ec == asio::error::would_block)
            awaitWriteable();
        else
            onDisconnected(ec);
    }
    return {sent, ec};
}
```

So the way reads work is

- `awaitReadable`.
- when readable, read everything until `would_block`.
- repeat.

and the way writes work is

- once connected `awaitWriteable`.
- when writeable, set a flag true, and if any data is pending, send as much as possible.
  if the send results in `would_block` then `awaitWriteable` again.
- when a client wants to send data, if the socket is currently writeable then "synchronously" send as much as possible.
  if the send results in `would_block` then buffer any unsent data and `awaitWriteable` again.

**Question:**

I would like to register my socket file descriptor with epoll, and leave it registered forever.

Is there any way to side-step this need to continually call `awaitReadable`/`awaitWriteable`?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing sync/async primitives. So at least the blanket claim *"It is configured non-blocking"* is inaccurate, because asio is having to switch it for you when you mix sync primitives.

**Note**: not all Asio-aware IO objects support this. E.g. Beast's `tcp_stream` (and `ssl_stream`) object do explicitly not support mixing synchronous and asynchronous operations.

> This necessarily involves a call to `epoll_ctl`, which effectively changes absolutely nothing.

Have you checked? Because it's up to the service implementation to decide how your handlers are serviced. It might be the case that fds are added and removed from the pollfd set. It might do cleverer things. It might not even use (e)poll on a particular system.

Regardless, is there something stopping you from using read operations directly in a loop. You can even used composed read operations, such as [`asio::async_read_until`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) or [`asio::async_read`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) with a CompletionCondition.

E.g. in to read incoming data in a loop, returning whenever 1024 bytes or more have been received:

```
void read_loop() {
    net::async_read(
        _socket, _read_buf, net::transfer_at_least(1024),
        [this](error_code ec, size_t xferred) {
            std::cout << "Received " << xferred //
                      << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

            if (!ec)
                read_loop();
        });
}
```

Here's a live demo reading itself:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f888464f152d68)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace net = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Client {
    Client(net::any_io_executor ex, tcp::endpoint ep) : _socket(ex) {
        _socket.connect(ep);
        assert(_socket.is_open());
        std::cout << "Connected " << ep << " from " << _socket.local_endpoint() << "\n";
    }

    void read_loop() {
        net::async_read(
            _socket, _read_buf, net::transfer_at_least(1024),
            [this](error_code ec, size_t xferred) {
                std::cout << "Received " << xferred //
                          << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

                if (!ec)
                    read_loop();
            });
    }

    auto get_histo() const {
        std::array<unsigned, 256> histo {0};
        auto f = buffers_begin(_read_buf.data()),
             l = buffers_end(_read_buf.data());
        while (f != l)
            ++histo[uint8_t(*f++)];
        return histo;
    }

  private:
    net::streambuf _read_buf;
    tcp::socket _socket;
};

int main() {
    net::io_context ioc;

    Client c(ioc.get_executor(), {{}, 8989});
    c.read_loop();

    ioc.run_for(10s); // time limit for online compilers

    // do something witty with the result
    auto histo = c.get_histo();
    for (uint8_t ch : {'a','q','e','x'})
        std::cout << "Frequency of '" << ch << "' was " << histo[ch] << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Connected 0.0.0.0:8989 from 127.0.0.1:48730
Received 1024 (Success)
Received 447 (End of file)
Frequency of 'a' was 38
Frequency of 'q' was 2
Frequency of 'e' was 92
Frequency of 'x' was 8
```

In about 10ms.

### BONUS: Profling `epoll_ctl` calls

Here is the same program eating a dictionay on my machine, while counting calls to `epoll_ctl`:

[image]

Note how only 3 `epoll_ctl` calls are ever issued:

```
Connected 0.0.0.0:8989 from 127.0.0.1:52974
Received 1024 (Success)
Received 1024 (Success)
Received 2048 (Success)
Received 4096 (Success)
Received 8192 (Success)
Received 16384 (Success)
Received 16384 (Success)
Received 16384 (Success)
Received 49152 (Success)
 ...
Received 65536 (Success)
Received 53562 (Success)
Received 0 (End of file)
Frequency of 'a' was 65630
Frequency of 'q' was 1492
Frequency of 'e' was 90579
Frequency of 'x' was 2139
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           epoll_ctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                     3           total
```

---

### Summary

Measure. Use async primitives to do the scheduling for you. The only reason to use `async_wait` *in principle* is when you have to call third-party code using the `native_handle` of the socket in response.

Comment: Added a simple profiling run showing that only 3 `epoll_ctl` calls are involved in the sample receiving a dictionary of 102k lines (971 KiB) in system-optimized buffer sizes going up to 64KiB

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! I've updated my question to show how I do writes, as I'd like to better understand your comment *"at least the blanket claim "It is configured non-blocking" is inaccurate, because asio is having to switch it for you when you mix sync primitives".* At no point (I think) will the socket be set blocking, and I am relying on receiving `would_block` back. Please could you comment on my updates?

Comment: A 2nd comment I'd like to make is that I will definitely need to use `boost::beast` in addition to my vanilla tcp client I've shown above, so if my current approach of attempting to send synchronously if the socket is writeable, and then buffering any unwritten data until the socket becomes writeable again and then sending the pending unwritten data won't work, then I guess I'll need to abandon this approach. Are you able to point me to where in the beast docs it says one cannot use this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worthy of a new question or just a comment. In retrospect I can see that I can just do an `async_read_some` call and it will work how I want. However, for writes, what I would like to do is first attempt to write synchronously as much as possible, and only if it `would_block` then buffer the remaining data, await the socket becoming writeable again and complete the write. Is this possible? Are the only choices a) send everything synchronously and block caller if all can't be sent immediately or b) start an async write which won't write anything immediately?

Comment: It looks like indeed Asio's socket type distinguishes `non_blocking` and `native_non_blocking` flags, so it may indeed not have been switching, TIL. I ran into this which might be interesting https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_seq_packet_socket/bytes_readable.html (although I'm not sure of the overhead of IOCTLs)

Comment: So the question becomes: does `epoll_ctl` get called unncessarily, and if so, why. Did you measure it for your use case? (Perhaps you can edit my minimal example to check)

Comment: I made some edits to your examle and reran doing my "read until `would_block`" and then `await_read` again - 528 calls to `epoll_ctl`. So it seems my approach is definitely suboptimal in this regard

Comment: even changing my code to use `async_read_some` with `socket.non_blocking(true)` results in `EPOLL_CTL` calls every time

Comment: Can you share it? It's probably something about the way read/write are alternated

Comment: Here it is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86d2fe5c4396d78e Thanks! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244670/discussion-between-sehe-and-steve-lorimer).